# JSON can't read returned ajax value

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have an ajax function that retrieve two values for a given post: one for the number of likes, another one for the `div` that contains all the people that liked that post.

Everything seems to work fine, the json retrieved is correct, but the printing result is incorrect. Every time I try to get the number of likes (`data.numDiLikes`) I always get `undefined` even though the json is saying `{"numDiLikes":"1","personeACuiPiace":"div info and stuff"}`, how do I fix this?

**AJAX with JSON**

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: "lib/ottieniCose.php",
    data: { like: "", id: valCOR, comOrisp: comOrisp },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data, textStatus){
        trova.find('.numDiLikes').first().replaceWith('<p class="numDiLikes">' + data.numDiLikes + ' mi piace</p>' + data.personeACuiPiace);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_POST['comOrisp'] == 'commento') {

        $commento->set_likes($_POST['id'], true);
    // number of people that liked the post
        $return_data['numDiLikes'] = $commento->get_likes($_POST['id'], true);
    // div with all the people who liked the post
        $return_data['personeACuiPiace'] = $commento->posso_fare_qualcosa($_SESSION['auth'], 'cancRisp', $_POST['id']);

    echo json_encode($return_data);exit;

}
```

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` for the success function in AJAX and see what it shows in console.

Comment: @Gothdo `{"numDiLikes":"1","personeACuiPiace":"div and stuff"}` as i said in the post. If you're interested in the full `personeACuiPiace` it's just a bunch of `<div><p></p></div>` stuff. The `personeACuiPiace` is being printed correctly, the `numDiLikes` is alwasys printed as `undefined` even though the console says `"numDiLikes":"1"` and should print `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dataType: "json"` to tell `$.ajax` that it returns JSON, and that it should parse it. `dataType: "html"` means that it returns HTML text, and `data` will be a string, not an object.

Comment: I just noticed that i put `dataType: "json"` on the first line and `dataType: "html"` on the sixth line of the ajax function, deleted `dataType: "html",` everything works fine now

Comment: I didn't even notice the duplicate property. A good IDE would have alerted you to that (I use JetBrains PhpStorm).